VSCodeの実行環境の把握方法を教えてください
PythonでChatGPTのAPIを動作させるためにSercret Keyを取得し以下のプログラムをVSCodeで作成しました。
VSCode上でRunボタンを押してもprintの結果はNoneとなり、Windowsコマンドラインから実行すると期待値が確認できました。
環境変数は setx で設定しています。VSCodeが実行する環境はどのように把握するのでしょうか。
また、VSCode用に環境変数を入力が必要であるなら、OS側に設定した環境変数を見てもらうにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。
from openai import OpenAI
import os

key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
print(key)


vscode を再起動してプログラムを実行し直したら環境変数が取得できるようにならないでしょうか？

こんな記事を読み解くことで理解が進むでしょう。【図解】わかりやすい環境変数の仕組み~Windows/Linuxの実用例と確認コマンド~, Windows 10 環境変数の設定と反映する方法, Windows環境変数の超基本を理解する為のアプローチ, Windowsにおける環境変数をあらためて整理する, PowerShellでWindows環境変数を“一覧確認・作成・変更・削除”する方法

@hiromasamasuda vscode再起動して解決しました。回答いただければプラス投票させていただきます。

@kunif 知りたかった本質的なことが勉強できました。回答いただければプラス投票させていただきます。

@de oogar hi さん、紹介した記事から何を読み取って理解・解決したのかについては貴方に帰属する内容ですので、自己回答にした方が良いでしょう。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。自分の質問に回答できますか？

環境変数は、プロセス起動時にロードされるため環境変数設定後に、環境変数を参照するプロセスを起動する必要があります。
よって、環境変数を設定後、VSCode を再起動してから、プログラムを実行してみてください。
また、デバッガーを使用している場合では、構成ファイル .vscode/launch.json が作成されていると思います。この構成ファイルに環境変数を設定可能です。
{    
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "OPENAI_API_KEY": "<your openai api key>"
            }
        }
    ]
}

configurations:env 以下に環境変数に設定したいキー、値を設定します。
launch.json で設定した環境変数は、デバッガー実行時のみに有効になります。OS レベルで環境変数を設定する必要がないため、開発時は、こちらの利用が良いかと思います。
